# Error embedding image in jupyter and exporting it to PDF with nbconvert

Tags: python

I have a Jupyter notebook and I am exporting it with nbconvert to PDF. When I do it, if I incorporate images, it gives me an error.

I do it with edit -> insert image, and save the image in the same folder as my jupyter document. The cell is Markdown.

I show my code to see the error:

```
![Captura%20de%20pantalla%20%2825%29.png](attachment:Captura%20de%20pantalla%20%2825%29.png)
```

When exporting it with nbconvert with the statement

```
jupyter nbconvert --to PDF --no-input REDACCION.ipynb
```

It gives me the following error:

```
(base) C:\Users\USUARIO\Desktop\DOC BECA COLABORACIÓN\CURSO AEROPYTHON-JUPITER>jupyter nbconvert --to PDF --no-input REDACCION.ipynb
[NbConvertApp] Converting notebook REDACCION.ipynb to PDF
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\USUARIO\anaconda3\Scripts\jupyter-nbconvert-script.py", line 10, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "C:\Users\USUARIO\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jupyter_core\application.py", line 270, in launch_instance
    return super(JupyterApp, cls).launch_instance(argv=argv, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\USUARIO\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\traitlets\config\application.py", line 845, in launch_instance
    app.start()
  File "C:\Users\USUARIO\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\nbconvert\nbconvertapp.py", line 350, in start
    self.convert_notebooks()
  File "C:\Users\USUARIO\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\nbconvert\nbconvertapp.py", line 524, in convert_notebooks
    self.convert_single_notebook(notebook_filename)
  File "C:\Users\USUARIO\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\nbconvert\nbconvertapp.py", line 489, in convert_single_notebook
    output, resources = self.export_single_notebook(notebook_filename, resources, input_buffer=input_buffer)
  File "C:\Users\USUARIO\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\nbconvert\nbconvertapp.py", line 418, in export_single_notebook
    output, resources = self.exporter.from_filename(notebook_filename, resources=resources)
  File "C:\Users\USUARIO\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\nbconvert\exporters\exporter.py", line 181, in from_filename
    return self.from_file(f, resources=resources, **kw)
  File "C:\Users\USUARIO\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\nbconvert\exporters\exporter.py", line 199, in from_file
    return self.from_notebook_node(nbformat.read(file_stream, as_version=4), resources=resources, **kw)
  File "C:\Users\USUARIO\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\nbconvert\exporters\pdf.py", line 183, in from_notebook_node
    self.run_latex(tex_file)
  File "C:\Users\USUARIO\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\nbconvert\exporters\pdf.py", line 153, in run_latex
    return self.run_command(self.latex_command, filename,
  File "C:\Users\USUARIO\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\nbconvert\exporters\pdf.py", line 141, in run_command
    raise raise_on_failure(
nbconvert.exporters.pdf.LatexFailed: PDF creating failed, captured latex output:
Failed to run "xelatex notebook.tex -quiet" command:
notebook.tex:446: Unable to load picture or PDF file '
notebook.tex:469: You can't use `
notebook.tex:470: Missing $ inserted
notebook.tex:471: You can't use `
notebook.tex:473: Missing $ inserted
dvipdfmx:fatal: Image inclusion failed for "attachment:Captura%20de%20pantalla%20%2825%29.png".

No output PDF file written.

Sorry, but xelatex did not succeed.

The log file hopefully contains the information to get MiKTeX going again:

  C:\Users\USUARIO\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\miktex\log\xelatex.log
```

Comment: I've just hit the same thing, I think, but via export to PDF from the menu. After many failed runs due to: missing pandoc, tex packages not installing, packages no longer containing expected files, etc. I finally got dvipdfmx:fatal: Image inclusion failed "png" (pngs are screengrabs in markdown cells). Did you eventually resolve the issue?

Answer (score -4):

This is a workaround but it genuinely works.

You need to trigger a print preview by clicking the "Print" button then to use browser "Save as PDF" to save the PDF:
[image]

[image]